# Django autocomplete light: Select2 not showing AJAX-updated selected option text

Tags: jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I have a [DAL](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) field with [`data-html`](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#displaying-results-using-custom-html) attribute and populated with [`Select2QuerySetView::get_queryset()`](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#create-an-autocomplete-view). I have overridden [`get_result_label()`](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#displaying-results-using-custom-html). For the **same queryset** result, `get_result_label()` may return **different labels** depending on some condition. The result labels are fetched correctly. But after selecting an option, its text displayed in the select box remains fixed even after it has subsequently changed and is re-selected from the dropdown list.

To demonstrate, here are some sequential screenshots. I am returning current time from `get_result_label()`.

1. Initial results, first option being selected.

[image: Initial results, first option being selected.]

2. First option selected (17:42:08). New results fetched.

[image: First option selected (17:42:08). New results fetched.]

3. Second option selected at 17:42:29. Shown correctly in box. New results fetched.

[image: Second option selected at 17:42:29. Shown correctly in box. New results fetched.]

4. First option with updated text (17:42:56) selected again. But in the box it still shows the original text (17:42:08).

[image: First option with updated text (17:42:56) selected again. But in the box it still shows the original text (17:42:08).]

Am I missing something? Or is there any workaround in DAL or [Select2](https://select2.org/)?

Answer (score 0):

Answering own question: After trial-and-error, found that clearing the HTML in [`select2:selecting`](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) event seems to be working.

```js
$(('#my_select2_id').on('select2:selecting', function(e) {
    $('#' + this.id).html('');
});
```

Not sure if this is the correct way, though.